# How to get the length of Future<List> from Assets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an

```
late final Future<List<String>> _exampleQuestionsFuture;
```

which is filled with values from a textfile:

```
 static Future<String> _getFileData() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test/test.txt');
  } 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _exampleQuestionsFuture =  _getFileData().then(const LineSplitter().convert);

  }
```

I want to use those values inside another function that takes the length of the generated _exampleQuestionsFuture as a parameter. Unfortunately I can't get this to work.

My current approach is not working:

```
late Future<int> lengthOfFile;

  static Future<int> _getFileLength() async{
    return  await _exampleQuestionsFuture.then((value) {
     return value.length;
   });
  }

//inside initState method
lengthOfFile = _getFileLength();
```

When I want to access the value I just get returned an **Instance of Future**

Is there any way to calculate this from a future?

Answer (score 3):

```
int lengthOfFile;

  static Future<int> _getFileLength() async{
    return  await _exampleQuestionsFuture.then((value) {
     return value.length;
   });
  }

//inside initState method
_getFileLength().then((value) {
if (value != null)
  setState(() {
    lengthOfFile = value;
  });
 });
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this workes , but int length =  

_getFileLength().then((value) {
 return value; 
});} not ?

Comment: because you need to call setState for updating widget tree

Comment: Is this really the reason? Isn't the setState(){} redundant, because I only calculate the length once. My approach returns with the int cannot be converted to Future<int>.  Why is it not equal to return a value to an int than to set the value in the then body.

Comment: the value will be set when future returns response, but setting some value doesn't automatically update the widget tree. if you need to avoid setState, you can use FutureBuilder widget which automatically update inner child when the value is set

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

remove the first return

```
static Future<int> _getFileLength() async{
     await _exampleQuestionsFuture.then((value) { // first return removed 
     return value.length;
   });
  }
```

Comment: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned ...

Comment: it should `await` for result to come .. and you can perform null check